# StartSSL certificate not trusted in Firefox and on Android

Tags: android, apache, firefox, ssl

Apache server, followed the guide from here: https://www.startssl.com/Support?v=21

httpd.conf:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!DH:!EXPORT:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL
SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/domain.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/private.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/1_root_bundle.crt"
```

Works fine in Chrome but Firefox yields the following error:

```
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

Analysis at https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html says the following:

*The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate. Learn more about this error. You can fix this by following StartCom's Certificate Installation Instructions for your server platform. Pay attention to the parts about Intermediate certificates.*

How can I make the chain valid?

Comment: That's the guide I linked to. I have added the chain file as seen in httpd.conf.

Comment: Which version of apache you are using because (from the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html):  *SSLCertificateChainFile became obsolete with version 2.4.8, when SSLCertificateFile was extended to also load intermediate CA certificates from the server certificate file.* Thus it might be that this setting is ignored which would fit the information about missing chain certificate in the ssl checker. Check error log of the server too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you, I was indeed using 2.4.23, for which the SSLCertificateChainFile directive is obsolete. Deleting that line in httpd.conf and executing cat 1_root_bundle.crt >> server.crt on the server did the trick. It now works correctly in Firefox and on Android. Would you consider making your comment an answer?

Comment: See also: [StartSSL certificate gives SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE in Firefox and ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in Chrome](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103405/startssl-certificate-gives-sec-error-revoked-certificate-in-firefox-and-err-cert) StartSSL certificates are no longer trusted by major browsers because the company messed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> SSLCertificateChainFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/1_root_bundle.crt"
> ```
>
> *... You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate*

The SSLCertificateChainFile option was obsoleted in Apache version 2.4.8 and any chain certificates need to be added to SSLCertificateFile instead. Since you are using 2.4.23 based on your comment this means that this setting was ignored. This means that no chain certificates were sent to the client, causing the validation error. You should have gotten a message in the error logs though pointing out the invalid setting.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can not. Mozilla was planning to distrust certificates issued by StartSSL for a period of one year starting in October 2016. Better use [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) as StartSSL (also known as StartCom is in trouble). What you see is probably that happening.

If curious you can read up more:

- [WoSign and StartCom issues summary document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C6BlmbeQfn4a9zydVi2UvjBGv6szuSB4sMYUcVrR8vQ/preview).
- [mozilla.dev.security.policy › Remediation Plan for WoSign and StartCom](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.security.policy/BV5XyFJLnQM).